# XSLT - How to unify text content of certain subsequent nodes?

Tags: xml, xaml, xslt

I'm pretty new to XSLT. I'm transforming a home brewed markup language to XAML. Due to historical reasons text components in the input XML are represented using individual nodes, even if they are part of the same paragraph.

**EDIT**

A paragraph really is determined by either a `<br/>` or by another non-text node following it. A non-text node is a node which should be rendered individually and not part of the paragraph such as a headline, eg `<h1>`; for simplicity we can assume that all nodes to be unified have a "text-" prefix, eg `<text-plain>`, `<text-bold>` etc.

(In the following examples, the output is pseudo code XAML as I'm not an experienced XAML developer.)

*Example 1*

```
<input>
  <text-plain>Hello World!</text-plain><text-bold>foo bar</text-bold><br/>
  <text-plain>Second line</text-plain><br/>
</input>
```

The above example should yield something like

```
<output>
  <TextBlock>Hello World!<bold>foo bar</bold></TextBlock>
  <TextBlock>Second line</TextBlock>
</output>
```

*Example 2*

```
<input>
  <text-plain>Hello World!</text-plain><text-bold>foo bar</text-bold>
  <h1>A headline breaking a paragraph</h1>
</input>
```

should yield

```
<output>
  <TextBlock>Hello World!<bold>foo bar</bold></TextBlock>
  <TextBlock><bold>A headline breaking a paragraph</bold></TextBlock>
</output>
```

I was thinking about using `following-sibling::`and/or `preceding-sibling::`, but, of course, there can be any number of nodes to be combined. How do I do that?

Comment: How do we know they are part of the same paragraph? Please post a more complete example, preferably showing at least two paragraphs in their parent element. - see [mcve].

Comment: So basically this is a grouping problem. Can you use XSLT 2.0? Also, what exactly is a "non-text node"?

Comment: @michael.hor257k I have to inquire about XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that if you can use XSLT 2.0, you could keep it (relatively) simple by doing:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/input">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="starts-with(name(), 'text-')">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="starts-with(name(), 'text-')">
                    <TextBlock>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                    </TextBlock>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text-plain">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text-bold">
    <bold>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </bold>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="br"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to the following test input:

**XML**

```
<input>
    <h1>Main Headline</h1>
    <text-plain>First line </text-plain>
    <text-bold>emphasises</text-bold>
    <text-plain> the first end.</text-plain>
    <br/>
    <text-plain>Second line.</text-plain>
    <h2>Aux Headline Breaking a Paragraph</h2>
    <text-plain>Third line </text-plain>
    <text-bold>boldens</text-bold>
    <text-plain> the third end.</text-plain>
</input>
```

the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <h1>Main Headline</h1>
   <TextBlock>First line <bold>emphasises</bold> the first end.</TextBlock>
   <TextBlock>Second line.</TextBlock>
   <h2>Aux Headline Breaking a Paragraph</h2>
   <TextBlock>Third line <bold>boldens</bold> the third end.</TextBlock>
</output>
```

Comment: I didn't think of starts-with - great! Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: It would have worked just as well with `matches(name(), 'text-.*')`.

Answer (score 0):

Using this XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <TextBlock>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </TextBlock>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text-plain">
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text-bold">
      <bold>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </bold>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="br">
      <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

with this input (I added a root node)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <text-plain>Hello World!</text-plain>
  <text-bold>foo bar</text-bold><br/>
</root>
```

results in your desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TextBlock>
  Hello World!
  <bold>foo bar</bold><br/>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Thanks. But that would render my second example as containing everything in one TextBlock node which is not what I want.

Comment: @Florian: You completely changed your question. So a satisfying answer would also be a completely different one.

Answer (score 0):

OK, like Michael suggested, this is a grouping problem. I have been able to solve this using two passes over the input: the first pass adds an attribute to all text-* nodes, the second pass uses this attribute to identify all adjacent nodes which should be group together under one TextBlock node.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>


<xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- store the modified content in a variable -->
    <xsl:variable name="preprocessed.doc">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="preprocess" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <!-- process the modified contents -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$preprocessed.doc/*" />
</xsl:template>


<!-- Preprocessing: add type attribute to all text-* nodes -->

<xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="preprocess">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="preprocess"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[name()[matches(.,'text-.*')]]" mode="preprocess">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:attribute name="type">text</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="preprocess"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<!-- Main processing: group text-* nodes, transform text-* nodes, etc. -->

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@type">
    <!-- Delete the type attributes from the final result -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="input">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="@type='text'">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="name()[matches(.,'text-.*')]">
                    <TextBlock>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                    </TextBlock>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text-plain">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text-bold">
    <bold>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </bold>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I don't see why you need two passes.